# ConEmu Separate Quake Style Hotkey

Tags: windows, hotkeys, conemu

I would like to be able to use ConEmu in "normal" mode, but also be able to press a hotkey to pull down a separate ConEmu in Quake mode.

It seems like it would be a useful hotkey because if I need to run a quick search or command I would not have to stop what I am doing in my main console.

Some (maybe) helpful info: I am running Windows 10 and primarily use ConEmu to run the Linux subsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have two different sets of hotkeys. And one of the instances you want to turn into Quake terminal.

Use named configuration for one of them. For example, to start "separate" Quake terminale run this

```
ConEmu64.exe -quake -config "Quake"
```

and choose appropriate hotkey to min/restore it.

Comment: Are you saying you can set unique hotkeys specific to an instance of ConEmu? I have tried changing the hotkeys but the problem is that it seems tha using a hotkey only affects the active ConEmu instance.

Comment: Re-read my answer carefully. I said you may set unique hotkeys per config.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you can have separate configs for different instances.